# httpwebrequest security exception

Tags: .net, silverlight, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to load a JSON list with a GET request to a PHP file on my localhost(WAMP) into my Silverlight+Webproj solution:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
request.BeginGetRequestStream(GetRequestStreamCallback, request);

    private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postInformation);
        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postInformation.Length);
        postStream.Close();
        request.BeginGetResponse(DownloadCompleted, request);
    }

    private void DownloadCompleted(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        ... load the data from the response , etc
}
```

This worked absolutely fine in the exact same way for another website. But now I'm getting this Security exception:

```
{System.Security.SecurityException ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult     asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.    <EndGetResponse>b__9(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at KunstWebsite.Model.Factory`1.DownloadCompleted(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)}
```

I tried solutions I found like adding clientaccesspolicy.xml, crossdomain.xml , putting localhost as a trusted site, adding trust level="Full" to my web.config. 
None of it seems to work...

Anyone any idea what I might have overlooked?

Comment: Could you provide Inner Exception?